# Getting column names of a view using CRM web API

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I’m using the CRM Online 2016 Web API. Now the only information I have is a savedQuery or userQuery record. With this I can get all records of the view, but I also want the column names of this view.

**Is there an easy way to get column names using the web API with only the information of a savedQuery/userQuery record?**

I already have an indirect way of getting the column names(using the LayoutXML).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [Use the Web API with Dynamics 365 metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607833.aspx), this allows you get to information about the entity structure.

Not 100% if this will be better than using the Layout XML, but worth considering.

Comment: Yeah, that is sort of what I use now. Using the LayoutXML to get the logical name. And using EntityDefinitions+logical name to get the display name(column name), but this creates problems with linked entities(which I had to work around).